# tempate function into a non-templated class?

Tags: c++, templates, class, function

I would like to add a "templated function" into a non-templated function like this :

```
class A
{
template <class T>
void Test<T>();
}

template <class T>
A::Test<T>();
```

But it tell me that I have an error in the .h file ! Is there a problem with this declaration ?

Remarks : my class MUST not be templated !

Thanks

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: I think you need to understand the role of templates in C++

Comment: Seven questions, no answers. Don't think I'm gonna post on this one.

Answer (score 6):

You can define a member function template as follows:

```
class A
{
    template <typename T>
    void Test()
    {
        ...
    };
};
```